# How should I address the memory usage of my Google Chrome extension?

Tags: memory, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I made a small extension which takes up about 20000k total memory when installed. I want to reduce this usage.

How should I start so that I address the problems having the greatest impact on the memory usage first?

Answer (score 2):

There is a powerful [Heap Profiler](http://code.google.com/chrome/devtools/docs/heap-profiling.html) built into Chrome dev tools.